# FB Api: Tag/mention another page on my own fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a fan page which I am an admin of. I'd like to create a simple button - when I click it, it would create a post on my Fanpage, with a predefined a message and a photo. I have been able to achieve this fairly simple using the Graph API:

```
 $args = array(
       'access_token'  => <my_acc_token>,
       'url'       => <url_of_image>,
       'message' => <my_message>
 );
 try{
    $facebook->api('/<id_of_my_page>/photos', 'POST', $args); 
 }catch(Exception $o ){
    print_r($o);
 }
```

**ISSUE**:
I would like to now be able to also Tag or Mention another page in that post, but nothing seems to work!

I tried adding a `@[user-id-of-page]` into the `message` property or my `$args` array - but to no avail.

Is tagging/mentioning even possible without having to use `Facebook actions`? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#pages

Be aware that you have to go through the review process with this, else you can only mention your own Pages.

So in order to mention other Pages, you would need to get the permissions `manage_pages` and `publish_actions` approved, and you need to get the "Page Mentions" feature approved. Go to "Status & Review" in your App settings and click on "Start a Submission". Scroll down in the list on the left and you will find "Page Mentions".

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm writing my code in PHP. I have seen this page but am unsuccessful in even publishing or mentioning my own page (I'm just testing before the app gets approved for being able to tag other pages). Could you please post an example of how the request would look, for me to be able to tag a page? Preferably in PHP if possible!

Comment: why the downvote? please comment, so i can improved my answer if needed. is any information missing?